# Gitlab : Understanding big symfony 2 project size

Tags: git, symfony

I have a big Symfony project in Gitlab with size 4.4 GB, and when I clone the project on my pc I found with the size with:
**Graphic mode is 1.2 GB** include :

- 400 MB web/upload (**not commited**)
- 140 MB vender  (**not commited**)
- 370 MB src **commited**

that means the real size of the project is up to 370 MB.
**Command line mode**
with command

```
 du -sh
```

the size of the project is 5.8 GB.

I can not understand the difference? Anyone knows why?

Comment: How many commits, branches, tags, etc. does this project have?

Comment: What does you mean by go, mo?

Comment: What's the size of the var/cache (or app/cache) directory? What's the Symfony version?

Comment: @StephanVierkant app/cache should be in the .gitignore as well

Comment: @kero : 1 branche , 30 tags

Comment: @Stephan : go == Giga octet, mo = mega octet

Comment: var/cache  is not commited

Comment: Why not using a English word for file sizes?

Comment: @Stephan : go == Gigabyte, mo = Megabyte

Comment: It was a rhetorical question: please use English only on this site ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size difference is very likely to be that only the CLI and Gitlab size include the history. Check the output of `du -sh .git/objects` which should be near what Gitlab will think about the size. In the graphical UI you might not see files starting with a dot, which might be the reason why `.git` was not included.